# iOS: View with datepicker and immediately keyboard visible very slow through segue

Tags: ios, keyboard, segue, uidatepicker

I have a view with a UIDatePicker (inserted in storyboard) and in which in the viewDidLoad instantly a textfield gets first responder status so the keyboard is visible.

This view loads quite slow (about 2 seconds the first time, 1 second thereafter). I've checked my app in the time profiler and nothing special visible. Just some peaks (as expected) during the segue, however none of my methods or code is responsible for that. After I've removed the UIDatePicker and the immediately visible keyboard it was a lot faster. But I need them both..any advice how to that? Can I preload this datepicker and the keyboard somehow and just reuse them?